# Can you add relationships to knowledge articles?

Tags: lookup, master-detail, knowledge, relationships, articles

It seems like the answer to this is no but I wanted to ask anyway.

Knowledge articles themselves dont allow a lookup or a mater-detail field.  And from what i can tell you cant add a lookup field that references an article on a custom object either.

So it seems like any and all relationships have to be through data categories.  Is that correct or am I missing something?

My hope was to have snippets (an article type specific to the user) that are related to other articles and build pages where they show up in the sidebar of articles, but it seems like that wouldnt be possible without creating a category for each of the the main articles?

Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While far from ideal, you could build your own add an article UI with Visualforce and store related articles as delimited ids in a text string on the article, which you then use to render in a VF sidebar widget.

Comment: ugh, yea thats what i was afraid of.  Looks like ill be avoiding knowledge articles for now.